# How to use ArrayList to populate choice list in a form

Tags: java, arraylist

I need to populate a choice component in a form with an ArrayList present in an external class (same package)

DatabaseList.java:
    package pmi.sqltoxml;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DatabaseList {
    public void SetLista() {
        ArrayList<String> db = new ArrayList<>();
        db.add("ADB_PMISOFTWARE");
        db.add("ADB_DEMO");
    }
}
```

MainForm.java:

```
public class Mainform extends javax.swing.JFrame {
DatabaseList db = new DatabaseList();

public Mainform() {
    initComponents();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private void initComponents() {
    choice1 = new java.awt.Choice();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    choice1.setName("dbList"); // NOI18N
    for (String dbItem : db ){
        choice1.add(dbItem);
    }

    ...
```

Netbeans tells me that

> `for-each` not applicable to expression type. Required `Array` or
>   `java.lang.iterable`. Found: `DatabaseList`.

But, `ArrayList` is not an `iterable` Interface?

Comment: Please stick to **naming conventions**. Class names are written in camel-case (first character upper-case) and method names, also variable names, start with a lower-case character.

Comment: *"But, `ArrayList` is not an `iterable` Interface?"* It actually is. See [Iterable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) *"All Known Implementing Classes"*. The type is inherited from `List` which is a `Collection` which is an `Iterable`.

Comment: @Nicola `ArrayList` *is* an `Iterable`. Your custom `DatabaseList` clas *isn't*.

Comment: @zabuza You're right, sorry, my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to return the List :

```
public List<String> setLista() {
    List<String> db = new ArrayList<>();
    db.add("ADB_PMISOFTWARE");
    db.add("ADB_DEMO");
    return db;//<------You have to return the list otherwise you can't use this array list
}
```

then you can call your method like this :

```
for (String dbItem : db.setLista()){
        choice1.add(dbItem);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the `db` List a `private` member of your class and add a getter (`getDb()`) in your `DatabaseList` class and iterate overt that (`for (String dbItem: db.getDb())`).

Or just make a `getList()` method that will return the `List`:

```
public class DatabaseList {
    public void getLista() {
        ArrayList<String> db = new ArrayList<>();
        db.add("ADB_PMISOFTWARE");
        db.add("ADB_DEMO");
        return db;
    }
}

for (String dbItem : db.getLista()){
        choice1.add(dbItem);
}
```

Your custom class `DatabaseList` is not a `List`/`Iterable` itself but a mere wrapper, therefore it can not be used in an [enhanced for loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).